# How to add parameters to jqgrid using setGridParam?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

This code is working properly:

```
$("#list").jqGrid({
...
postData: { filters:'{"groupOp":"AND","rules":[{"field":"category_id","op":"eq","data":"mydata"}]}' },
search: true,
...
});
```

i tried to add these parameters using setGridParam method:

```
jQuery("#list").setGridParam({
    postData: { filters:'{"groupOp":"AND","rules":[{"field":"category_id","op":"eq","data":"mydata"}]}' },
    search: true,
}).trigger('reloadGrid');
```

But it doesn't work

Comment: It's important to know in which context (inside of which callback or just where in your code) you use `setGridParam` with `reloadGrid`. Which `datatype` you use? Do you want to filter the data locally or remotely (load filtered data from the server)? Which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)? Do you have the demo, which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: i tried to use `setGridParam` in different cases(in `gridComplete` or separately from the grid). data is loaded from the server. i'm using version 4.6.0.

Comment: You should include more full JavaScript code, which you use. If you use `datatype: "json"` and load the data from the server (and if you don't use `loadonce: true`) then **the server** is responsible for filtering the data. Free jqGrid, the fork which I develop, allows to load the data from the server and then to sort and filter the data *before* the first page will be displayed in the grid. See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/formEditOnDoubleClick-jqueryui-fa1.htm), where one can use `url: ..., datatype: "json", loadonce: true` instead of `data: mydata`.